# unable to use rosrun with arduino

Tags: rosserial, rosserial-arduino

rosrun rosserial_
Usage: rosrun [--prefix cmd] [--debug] PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please edit your post to tell us: 1) which version of ros you are using, 2) what OS and version you are using, 3) did you build rosserial from source or install it from binary repo, 4) how is arduino connected to this machine (rs-232?), 5) a link to the tutorial you followed to set up rosserial.